# cant make it: Ruby on Rails passenger-nginx configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

My system is Arch linux. I try to install passenger-nginx by using the command "rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module".

My application is in " ~/rails_projects/myPedia " directory. When i try to run server via "nginx" ; I get this error:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2012/06/24 00:25:46 [emerg] 8853#0: open() "/var/log/nginx/access.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

What must be the correct permissions for those files or my user?

And in my  /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf is :

```
    http {
        passenger_root /home/ytsejam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.13;
        passenger_ruby /home/ytsejam/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby;
    ................
        server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  localhost;
            location /home/ytsejam/rails_projects/myPedia
            passenger_enabled on
    }
}
```

Is location set correctly for my application directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gives user running nginx  write permission to "/var/log/nginx/error.log". 
And fix location path:

```
location /home/ytsejam/rails_projects/myPedia/public
```

Comment: Thanks.. Now I can make nginx work. Now I have to fix 403 error.